# is it best practice to bind uncaughtException event to handle error occurs in callback nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
 var customError = function (){
    try{
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("time out called");
            throw new Error ("Error in call back");
        },5000);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
customError();

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
})
```

I read some blogs and find we can use "uncaughtException" process event for handling the errors occurs in callback. But on the other hand I read instead of "uncaughtException" you should use promise library.  But "uncaughtException" event working fine with me. I just want to know is it best practice to handle callback error or not ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt really handle 'uncaughtException' as you dont know where its coming from(your application or NodeJS).

> An unhandled exception means your application - and by extension
>   Node.js itself - is in an undefined state. Blindly resuming means
>   anything could happen.

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception

Joyent has a good article on handling errors in NodeJS at https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors

Comment: Thanks, after reading joyent article most of my doubts get cleared now.

Answer (score 0):

*This is extentded version of @Josnidhin's answer.*

Typically you should handle the exceptions as and when they occurr or pass it to callee. for passing to callee you can use

1. Passing `err` as first parameter(standard accepted by Node.js community) to callback function. [callback patter]
2. You may want to use promises instead of callback pattern.

you should also subscribe to event `uncaughtException` in order to know that something crappy has happened and now onwards server may go to some inconsistent state. Here you may want to send mailer to admin stating the details of exception occurred or restarting the server itself.